# How do I generate a DER encoded public key with OpenSSL in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, openssl, cryptography, minecraft

I have been developing a Minecraft server software and having some trouble generating a DER encoded public key with OpenSSL in C/C++.

https://wiki.vg/Protocol_Encryption (The documentation of making a server software) says this:

```
The server generates a 1024-bit RSA keypair on startup. 
The public key is sent in the Encryption Request packet in DER encoding format. 
More technically, it is in ASN.1 format as defined by x.509 with the structure looking as follows.

SubjectPublicKeyInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
  algorithm SEQUENCE {
    algorithm         OBJECT IDENTIFIER
    parameters        ANY OPTIONAL
  }
  subjectPublicKey  BITSTRING
}

SubjectPublicKey ::= SEQUENCE {
  modulus           INTEGER
  publicExponent    INTEGER
}
```

Here is my current code:

```
RSA* rsa = RSA_new();
if (!rsa)
    return false;

BIGNUM* exponent = BN_new();
if (!exponent)
{
    RSA_free(rsa);
    return false;
}

EVP_PKEY* pkey = EVP_PKEY_new();
if (!pkey)
{
    RSA_free(rsa);
    BN_free(exponent);
    return false;
}

BN_set_word(exponent, 65537);
RSA_generate_key_ex(rsa, 1024, exponent, NULL);

EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA(pkey, rsa);

// Write the DER encoded public key
std::vector<uint8_t> derPublicKey;
{
    derPublicKey.resize(1024);
    
    X509* x509 = X509_new();
    X509_set_pubkey(x509, pkey);
    
    uint8_t* keyPtr = derPublicKey.data();
    int keyLength;
    if (!(keyLength = i2d_X509(x509, &keyPtr)))
    {
        RSA_free(rsa);
        BN_free(exponent);
        return false;
    } derPublicKey.resize(keyLength);

    X509_free(x509);
}

// Free everything
RSA_free(rsa);
BN_free(exponent);
EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
```

This code compiles, but the client connecting still says in the log "Public key reconstitute failed" with no further information. Can someone explain how this can be done? Thanks.

*PS: I have very little knowledge about cryptography. I am only doing this project for fun.*

Comment: My current code isn't even close to being correct and nothing else I have tried is. I didn't feel like it would help very much, but I'll include my current code anyways.

Comment: I think you need to use `i2d_PUBKEY` and let the function itself perform the memory allocation. It seems that you can call it directly on the `PKEY` instance. It's a terribly named function by the way, but yeah, OpenSSL.

Comment: It works! Thank you, @Maarten Bodews.